# how to add element using swift to a storyboard stackview

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I am a beginner so sorry if it is a stupid question but I am trying to add new elements to a stack view that was made with a storyboard. I want to do it every time a button was pressed and I want the same color, size, constraint... how do I do this?

[here is an image of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQAgB.png)

[and this is the image of my storyboard structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwzUR.png)

[and this is what I made with the storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RW2c.png)

and I want to add another button like the other ones every time the settings button is pressed
pls, can anyone help?

Comment: Please post code as text. Don't post images of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect your stack view to an `@IBOutlet` such as:

```
@IBOutlet var stackView: UIStackView!
```

Instead of trying to "copy" the button you designed in Storyboard, use a function to create a new button with your desired properties:

```
func makeNewButton() -> UIButton {
    // create a button
    let b = UIButton()
    // set your desired font
    b.titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 18.0, weight: .light)
    // set background color to your desired light-green
    b.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.85, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
    // set title colors for normal and highlighted
    b.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    b.setTitleColor(.gray, for: .highlighted)
    return b
}
```

Now, your function for tapping the "Settings" button could look like this:

```
@IBAction func settingsButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    // call func that returns a new button with your
    //  desired colors, font, etc
    let newButton = makeNewButton()
    // set the title (presumably you'll be getting a new title string from somewhere)
    newButton.setTitle("New Button", for: [])
    // give it an action
    newButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.btnTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    // add it to the stack view
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(newButton)
}
```

---

**Edit** the above code assumed an existing function for handling the button action - such as:

```
@objc func btnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // do something when the button is tapped
    print("A button was tapped...")
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for responding this mostly works i got an error tho with the action of the new button it is saying "Value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'btnTapped'" my code is the same as what you sent

Comment: @DominikDev - that was just an example... As with setting the Title for the new button, I assume you would already have code to handle taps from your newly added buttons. See the edit to my answer.